# Controlling power to an SD card

Tags: pic, mosfet

I'm working on a low power application. With a PIC24F (3.3V) I want to control the power to an SD card, turning it on and off. Typical current draw is 50mA, but can go as high as 200mA. I already have a 3.3V supply.

I was thinking of something using a 2N7000 MOSFET. What gate-source voltage would saturate these? Is it possible to do this on the high side or will it have to be on the low side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Low-side configuration are fine for simple loads like relays or lights, but you don't want to use a low-side configuration in this case, since it would place the ground of the SD card at a different level than the ground for the PIC24, which would interfere with the logical levels used to drive the data interface.

I like to use P-channel MOSFET's in a high-side configuration for this purpose, with the gate tied to the source lead through a 499K resistor to keep the device off when starting up.   You can then turn the MOSFET on by configuring the pin on the PIC24 in an open-drain configuration and driving it low.

You want a P-channel MOSFET with a very low Rds (below 1 ohm) and low Vgs, such as [this one](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=NDS352APCT-ND).  (I couldn't find any that met your criteria in a thru-hole package.)  The MOSFET you chose (2N7000) has an Rds of 5 ohms, which means there would be a 1 volt voltage drop at 200 ma.

Here's a [document](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/vishay/70611.pdf) that explains why it is best to use P-channel MOSFET's in a high-side configuration.

Comment: Thanks! I will use a P-ch fet then - sounds great. Through hole/surface mount is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use a TPS2041B device from TI. This is a high side switch with low on resitance and overcurrent protection.